# How to support GNU/Linux on lenovo g470 laptop ? fans, mic, sdcard etc

Tags: display, fan, lenovo-laptop, acpi

I recently got a lenovo g470  I use it under GNU/Linux debian and update my notes at :

http://rzr.online.fr/q/lenovo

Maybe it's a too recent model to get support, but I bet this is also affecting other intel based laptop ...

First issue : the left fan is always on after a couple of minutes ... how to monitor its rpm and control it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is better asked at http://forum.thinkpads.com/ or http://www.thinkwiki.org/

Comment: hi thank you for this advice I just joined :

http://forum.thinkpads.com/search.php?author_id=52358&sr=posts